# Why can my GSA not sort when ORs are used?

Tags: google-search-appliance

In our GSA I am trying to retrieve documents that either have a "XosContentType" metadata tag of either "article" or "ooyala".  To do retrieve this I run the following search command:

```
/search?q=&access=p&output=xml_no_dtd&num=7&start=0&filter=0&requiredfields=(XosContentType%3aarticle%7cXosContentType%3aooyala)&sort=date:D:R:d1
```

While this gives me results correctly matching my requiredfields criteria they are not sorted at all.  For example, the following are the order of the  nodes I am receiving

```
<FS NAME="date" VALUE="2012-07-13"/>
<FS NAME="date" VALUE="2012-07-25"/>
<FS NAME="date" VALUE="2012-05-23"/>
<FS NAME="date" VALUE="2012-03-10"/>
<FS NAME="date" VALUE="2012-05-15"/>
```

And it just goes on and on like this.  If I only search by one criteria then everything sorts correctly, but using both fails sorting.

So how can I get sorting to work properly?  I really don't want to have to do searches and combine the results myself because that will massively complicate paging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to supply a query term to sort by date.  Try switching your required fields  filter to be inmeta.

See this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/Google-Search-Appliance-Help/8oSW7nZBMuw

Comment: That's not it, because if I only search for XosContent:article or I only search for XosContent:Ooyala everything sorts properly.  In fact, this has been the case in production for 4 months with no issues.

Comment: Nevermind, it does appear that you are correct, and it's just a fluke that it works with one criteria.

Comment: Hah I got around the problem by just specifying "q=http"

Comment: Right.  That's a way to trick it because most of your content probably contains http.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a query term of

```
site:mywebsite.com
```

But that will only work if all your data belongs to the same domain.